# React-Native project won't run on the right node -v for EAS IOS build

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, yarnpkg, eas

I have a project I'm trying to create an IOS build for using EAS ("eas build --platform ios").  With everything I've tried I keep getting this error on the expo.dev site claiming that I'm trying to use an outdated node (16.18.1) when I have 18.18.0.

Running "yarn install" in /Users/expo/workingdir/build directory
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[stderr] error rooms-ios@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "18.18.0". Got "16.18.1"
[stderr] error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Unknown error. See logs of the Install dependencies build phase for more information.

I used to be able to build this project in eas, and I've tested the IPA files 30+ times.  I don't know what happened.

**HERES WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

- I've deleted and reinstalled node to the latest version.
- I've run the 'nvm install 18.18.0' & 'nvm use 18.18.0' commands, getting these results:
  'Version 18.18.0 is already installed.'
  'Now using node v18.18.0 (64-bit)'
- I've made sure that the 'engines' section of my package.json file looks like this:
  "engines": {
  "node": "18.18.0",
  "yarn": "^1.22.17"
  },
- I've done a "npm cache clean -f" a "yarn cache clean" and a fresh "yarn install"
- I've update my 'Path' in 'Environmental Variable' to make sure %NVM_HOME% and %NVM_SYMLINK% get looked at first.

Should I just try rebuilding my project using npm instead of yarn?  Is that my issue?